# JavasScript function find and replace multiple items

Tags: javascript, function

I'd like to ask another JS related question. I need a javascript function to find and replace multiple items in a string.

For example: all instances of "identifier" should be replaced with "ID" and all instances of "amount" should be replaced with "value".

Many thanks in advance!

Adriaan Boot

```
[ 
  {identifier: '97307', amount: '2.99', currency: 'EUR', quantity: '2'},
  {identifier: '113266', amount: '79.99', currency: 'EUR', quantity: '1'} 
]
```

Comment: Please tell us : is your variable really a string or an object ? (to check : did it show text when you pass it in alert() ?)

Answer (score 0):

what you have there is not a string, it looks like a javascript object, or json object. IF this was a string, then you would use replace(oldstring, newstring) OR replaceAll(oldstring, newstring)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are working on an array objects and not a string and want to replace the objects' property names, you can do so as such:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < myArray.length ; i++){
    //create a new property with desired name
    myArray[i].ID = myArray[i].identifier;
    //delete old property
    delete myArray[i].identifier;

    myArray[i].amount = myArray[i].value;
    delete myArray[i].value;
}
```

If, however, you are in fact dealing with strings consider using the `replace` function.

Answer (score -1):

You must do some research before posting question, to avoid us giving you response you may already know.
BTW, this problem is quite straightforward :

```
var str = "[ 
  {identifier: '97307', amount: '2.99', currency: 'EUR', quantity: '2'},
  {identifier: '113266', amount: '79.99', currency: 'EUR', quantity: '1'} 
]";
var res = str.replace("identifier", "ID").replace("amount", "value");
```

Comment: OP is not using a string; it's an object. The `replace()` method only exists on `String`.

Comment: It's not because it looks like an object that it is actually an object. As the OP said it is a string, we can take it as a string and use replace.

Comment: If OP literally gave us an array of objects, that's what we take it as. It seems OP is new and may be more likely to be confusing strings with other data types, or did not type it clearly.

Comment: I suppose we are somewhere both right. Let the OP try and see who deserve his green cross:)

Answer (score -1):

To clarify: are you trying to change the key name, or the value of the key?

If the latter:

You can iterate through the array and, if the key exists in that object, replace the value. Example:

```
// i will set the array you gave above to 'arr'
arr.forEach(function(s) {
 if(s.identifier) {
   s.identifier = 'ID';
 }
 if(s.amount) {
   s.amount = 'value';
 }
});
```

If 'amount' and 'identifier' for certain exist on all the objects in the array, ignore the conditional `if` statements.

If you are trying to replace the actual object key/property names, there are ways to do that as well. I don't think that's what you're trying to say so I'll ignore it for now. Comment back if that's what you're trying to do and I can update my answer.

Comment: OP asked speciffically a function for replacement in a string. If you provide code for object/array, please note it.